# Condionally apply CSS to element in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, css, aurelia

I have an array of items and I want to apply style class to an element which has my customname.

The style is not applying for any element. How can apply style based on condition?

```
var items =["one","two","three"];

<li repeat.for="item of items" class="${item == 'one'? 'someclass':''}">${item}</li>
```

Comment: Notice that you are missing double quote around the value *three*. And use === to compare.

Comment: No luck Benny.!

Comment: The syntax you are using seems to be correct, try to look for other things that might be going wrong? Are you importing the stylesheet properly? Did you spell the classname correctly?

Comment: Yes everything is correct. I am suspecting that,, we are using conditional check while iterating items and the value is not available when the comparison is happend.

Comment: I have the same syntax in my project and it works fine, so that's not an issue.

Comment: Try something really simple and stupid: replace the condition with *${true ? ‘someclass’ : ‘’}* to  neutralize some of your logic and check if the condition is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=ed73adef9c634efbfc4dd109a68ec2c2**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <h1>${message}</h1>

  <ul ref="ul">
    <li repeat.for="item of items" class="${item == 'one' ? 'someclass' : ''}">
      ${item}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h4>Resulting HTML:</h4>
  <pre><code>${debug}</code></pre>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  message = 'Hello World!';
  items = ["one","two","three"];

  get debug() {
    return this.ul.outerHTML;
  }
}
```